# SWFUpload "addPostParam" doesn't work

Tags: jquery, upload, swfupload

I've been testing this upload script and it looks really good, but i just can't get it to post values, that i have extracted from inputs. Everything is looking good and it seems I'm writing everything correctly but it just stops `SWF DEBUG: Event: uploadStart : File ID: SWFUpload_0_0`,
there's my piece of code which causes these troubles

> `.bind('uploadStart', function(event,
>   file){    $(this).addPostParam(
>   "title", "asd"); })`

I'm using it as jquery plugin, maybe that's the problem? Thanks!

Comment: This http://blogs.bigfish.tv/adam/2009/06/14/swfupload-jquery-plugin/

Comment: I'm not familiar with this plugin (which really doesn't mean much in itself) but I've used Uploadify (http://www.uploadify.com/) and Jquery Ajax File Upload Plugin (http://www.phpletter.com/Demo/AjaxFileUpload-Demo/) with good success.  This isn't much of an answer to your questions so I'm listing the suggestions here.

Comment: Well thanks for your help, but i would like to have uploader that has progress bar and i could be able to send additional data from text fields? Uploadify doesn't seem to have this feature and other one just uploads :( Maybe you could recommend something similar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the docs on the project page it looks like you will need to use this code to get an instance of the SWFUpload object to call addPostParam on

```
var swfu = $.swfupload.getInstance('.some-selector-for-your-control');
```

I think the this reference inside of that event handler refers to the jQuery wrapper around the SWFUpload object.