# how to sending extra parameter (key/value) to an asp.net page using swfupload

Tags: asp.net, swfupload

we are using swfupload for the sake of uploading process in our project but we need add some extra parameter and send them via swfupload to aps.net page

how can I do this?
is it possible at all to passing extra parameters to a server-side page by using swfupload?

regards.

Comment: Have the same question here.  For more description... I'm uploading photos to a URL that takes a parameter for the actual file data, one for the title of the photo, and one for a description of the photo.  I need to set the title of the photo to be the name of the file that was selected.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you can use the addPostParam method to add parameters which will be sent back for each file uploaded:

http://demo.swfupload.org/Documentation/#addPostParam

You might also check out this related SO question: [SWFUpload "addPostParam" doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2796322/swfupload-addpostparam-doesnt-work)

Comment: I'll give you the bounty once the 24 hour limit is up.  I was aware of addPostParam but needed a way to set parameters for individual files when queuing.  But clicking your link, I happened to see addFileParam right below, which is what I need.

Comment: @Mike Ruhlin: Glad this led you to the answer.  Sometimes that's the best we can do ;)

Answer (score 0):

This might answer your question, but not mine.  You can call `swfUploader.addPostParam` to add parameters to all the files being uploaded.

If you're queueing up multiple files like I am, this won't help you because it applies to ALL files in the queue, not each individual file.  But if you're only uploading one file, you might be OK.